# Measuring process peak memory usage post mortem

Tags: winapi

I'm working on a benchmark tool which among other things measures the time and memory used by an external process performing an operation. I'm mostly interested in the peak pageable memory size (a.k.a. PageFileBytesPeak performance counter / Process.PeakPagedMemorySize64 / peak private bytes). This is a .NET project so a pure .NET solution would be preferable, however this is most likely not a possibility.

The problem here is that I won't know the peak memory usage before the process has exited. I can't read the performance counters for the process when it no longer exists. So I could instead poll it while the process is running.

However this is not preferable as if I poll too often I will interfere with the time it takes for the process to complete its work, and if poll too rarely the result won't be accurate (the process will most likely hit its peak memory usage right before it exits). So I'm hoping there is some way to do it reliably that is less hacky than the solutions I have come up with so far:

1. Inject DLL into process, report value via IPC mechanism on DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.
2. Patch/Hook ExitProcess in target process, report value via IPC mechanism before executing real ExitProcess.
3. Pretend to be a debugger, measure value on EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT (the process won't be cleaned up by the kernel before ContinueDebugEvent is called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) works even after the process has exited as long as you have an active handle to it. The virtual memory usage isn't available this way though if you happen to need that.

Only caveat is that the size of the values depends on the bitness of the process it's called from, so the values may overflow if a 32 bit process measures the memory usage of a 64 bit process.

Example:

```
[DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool GetProcessMemoryInfo(IntPtr hProcess, out PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS counters, int size);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS
{
    public uint cb;
    public uint PageFaultCount;
    public UIntPtr PeakWorkingSetSize;
    public UIntPtr WorkingSetSize;
    public UIntPtr QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
    public UIntPtr QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    public UIntPtr QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
    public UIntPtr QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    public UIntPtr PagefileUsage;
    public UIntPtr PeakPagefileUsage;
}

public long BenchmarkProcessMemoryUsage(string fileName, string arguments)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arguments);
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process process = Process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS counters;
    if (!GetProcessMemoryInfo(process.Handle, out counters, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS))))
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    return (long)counters.PeakPagefileUsage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading extant PerfMon counters should be a very low overhead operation, esp. for system counters like the ones you want to work with, since the counters are typically (possibly always? not sure) implemented using a block of shared memory (mapped file).

I'd implement polling with a runtime configurable interval, and only resort to more complex techniques if you find this is affecting your application materially.  If you want to sanity check this first, set up PerfMon to monitor the counter(s) of interest and see if that kills your application when running at a usable refresh interval.

Comment: Even disregarding the possibility of interfering with the time used I still have the problem that the process in question might allocate a large amount of memory within its last quantum which would mean I can't see it if my code is scheduled on the same core as the thread allocating the memory no matter how fast I'm polling. The operation may take less than 200ms to complete, and with a quantum of around 180ms on server systems I wouldn't even have a chance to get a time slice between the process starts and exits.

Comment: I agree that if you are this concerned about a huge spike on process closedown (or between polls), polling is not sufficient.  I just wonder if this is really as much of a problem as you think, given the extra cost of instrumenting for it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a benchmark tool which primary purpose is to benchmark new backends (it is actually for testing different engines for pdf conversion and concatenation, but that isn't really relevant for the question), so you might be right and it won't be neccessary, but I can't know that beforehand. Seems like I will have to go the dll injection route.