# How can I measure memory usage of 64-bit process in 32-bit program ?

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi, performancecounter

I'm trying to measure process memory usage (`WorkingSetSize`) of 64-bit applications from a 32-bit process in C++. I tried using `Toolhelp`:

```
void GetProcMemoryInfo(const wchar_t * procName)
{
     PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
     entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

     HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

     if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
     {
         while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
         {
             if (wcscmp(entry.szExeFile, procName) == 0)
             {
                 HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
                 PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS objProcessMemoryInfo;

                 if (GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, &objProcessMemoryInfo, sizeof(objProcessMemoryInfo)))
                 {
                      wchar_t szProcessMemoryInfo[100];
                      wsprintf(szProcessMemoryInfo, L"Working Set Bytes (MB): %d\n", objProcessMemoryInfo.WorkingSetSize / (1024 * 1024));
                      OutputDebugString(szProcessMemoryInfo);
                 }
                 CloseHandle(hProcess);
             }
         }
     }
     CloseHandle(snapshot);
}
```

This solution works fine, but only if it's build as `x64` application. Otherwise - I get maximum value of `2^32`. I guess the case is that `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` uses `SIZE_T` internally. Is there any other way to measure process memory usage,  insensitive to architecture it's build against ?

Comment: Do this from a 64 bit process, rather then from inside the emulator

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the bottom line is i have to do it from 32 bit process. The application that will be using it is 32 bit.

Comment: As alredy mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574638/measuring-process-peak-memory-usage-post-mortem, the size of the fields in the structure are defined by ht calling process'es bitness and overflow may happen if the measured process is a x86-64 one. So use a x86-64 process to do measurements. You can write a "proxy" application that would only measure memory uasage being x86-64, and then pass the value to the original x86 process (via remoting or any other IPC).

Comment: @EduardMalakhov I know this - if I could use `x86-64` there would be no question - and using some kind of proxy is my last resort.  But it would complicate the architecture and i want to avoid it at all cost.

Comment: @pSoLT That's the only solution.

Comment: Ah well, sometimes you just have to give up in the face of unrealistic constraints.

Comment: Write it as an out-of-process COM server.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, come and take a look.

Comment: @EduardMalakhov as well.

Comment: Sure, WMI gets it done with an external 64 bit process. Doesn't work on machines with WMI disabled which does happen. And is painfully slow. But if it meets your requirements, great.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - but it's called form 32 bit process, so it's fine for me. I am just concerned about resource consumption of WMI ( i haven't used it before ). The code below would be called periodically every minute. Can it cause some significant impact on resource usage ?

Comment: Well, it not work at all on some machines. I'd be looking to avoid WMI if possible and use a 64 bit process. Out of proc com would be one way to do that and have your main app remain 32 bit. Working set size probably isn't the right measure of memory usage.

Comment: Whoever minused the question, please share what bright thought lead you to the conclusion that there is something wrong with the question i asked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it can be done with the use of `Windows Management Instrumentation`:

```
class WMI 
{
public:
     WMI();
    ~WMI();
     HRESULT Open(LPCTSTR machine=NULL, LPCTSTR user=NULL, LPCTSTR pass=NULL);
     void Close();
     HRESULT GetProcStringProperty(DWORD pid, TCHAR *name, TCHAR *value, DWORD len);
     int GetLastError();

private:
     IWbemServices *wbem;
     HRESULT result;
     BSTR GetProcQuery(DWORD pid);
};
```

To value of a property is retrieved using following function:

```
HRESULT WMI::GetProcStringProperty(DWORD pid, TCHAR *name, TCHAR *value, DWORD len)
{
    IWbemClassObject *obj;
    VARIANT var;

    result = wbem->GetObject(GetProcQuery(pid), 0, 0, &obj, 0);

    if (FAILED(result)) {
        return result;
    }

    result = obj->Get(name, 0, &var, 0, 0);

    if (SUCCEEDED(result)) {
        if (var.vt == VT_NULL) {
            result = E_INVALIDARG;
        }
        else {
            lstrcpyn(value, var.bstrVal, len);
        }
        VariantClear(&var);
    }

    obj->Release();

    return result;
}
```

The value of memory usage is retrieved using following function:

```
int wmiGetMemProc(uint64_t pid, uint64_t *procmem)
{
    int status;
    TCHAR buf[MEM_MAX];
    WMI *wmi = new WMI();

    if (FAILED(wmi->Open())) {
        return wmi->GetLastError();
    }

    if (FAILED(wmi->GetProcStringProperty(pid, L"WorkingSetSize", buf, MEM_MAX))) {
        status = wmi->GetLastError();
    }
    else {
        *procmem = _wcstoui64(buf, NULL, 10);
    }

    wmi->Close();
    delete wmi;

    return status;
}
```

It works just fine.